# how can i call an function present in backend while clicking the button from frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

This is my button in my frontend

```
  <button /*onClick={say.stop()}*/ className='stopspeech'>
    Stop speaking
  </button>
```

And I want to call this say.stop() function with a click, and this say.stop() function is in my backend.

So how can add a new endpoint in my backend which calls this function on clicking the button.
I want this in express.

Comment: Do you already have express configured and using other endpoints? I ask because you wrote "new endpoint" so I'm assuming there's already something there that you can copy.

Comment: Are both backend and frontend going to be packed as a single application for desktop (using Electron or similar), or is it going to run on a webserver that users can access via an URL?

Comment: yes i have already added  end points. And my backend and frontend are not packed as you said, its with url.